# R - ggplot - Error in function, arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I'm having trouble plotting fixed effects from an lmer model.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(effects)

data(diamonds)

m1 <- lmer(carat ~ price * depth + (1 | cut), diamonds)
summary(m1)
ee <- Effect(c("price", "depth"), m1)
ggplot(data.frame(ee), aes(price, fit, color = cut)) + geom_line()
```

When I use ggplot I get this error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   function. Defaulting to continuous. Error in (function (..., row.names
>   = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 0

but a simple `plot(ee)` yields 5 tiled plots:

[image]

A different model yields a plot:

```
m3 <- lmer(price ~ depth * clarity + (1 | cut), diamonds)
summary(m3)
eg <- Effect(c("depth", "clarity"), m3)
ggplot(as.data.frame(eg), aes(depth, fit, color = clarity)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

There does not appear to be a mismatch in the number of rows per column:

```
> as.data.frame(ee)
   price depth       fit         se     lower     upper
1    330    40 0.4618286 0.04227714 0.3789651 0.5446922
2   5000    40 0.7931920 0.04074246 0.7133365 0.8730476
3   9600    40 1.1195885 0.04366662 1.0340016 1.2051754
4  14000    40 1.4317938 0.04988618 1.3340165 1.5295711
5  19000    40 1.7865726 0.05966749 1.6696239 1.9035214
6    330    50 0.4566107 0.03977778 0.3786459 0.5345754
7   5000    50 0.8690398 0.03930531 0.7920010 0.9460785
8   9600    50 1.2752869 0.04021511 1.1964649 1.3541088
9  14000    50 1.6638710 0.04228263 1.5809968 1.7467453
10 19000    50 2.1054440 0.04584704 2.0155834 2.1953045
11   330    60 0.4513927 0.03870323 0.3755341 0.5272513
12  5000    60 0.9448875 0.03868697 0.8690608 1.0207143
13  9600    60 1.4309852 0.03871997 1.3550938 1.5068767
14 14000    60 1.8959482 0.03879694 1.8199059 1.9719906
15 19000    60 2.4243153 0.03893796 2.3479966 2.5006340
16   330    70 0.4461747 0.03917094 0.3693994 0.5229501
17  5000    70 1.0207353 0.03892648 0.9444391 1.0970315
18  9600    70 1.5866836 0.03940454 1.5094504 1.6639168
19 14000    70 2.1280255 0.04050652 2.0486324 2.2074186
20 19000    70 2.7431867 0.04245996 2.6599648 2.8264085
21   330    80 0.4409568 0.04112833 0.3603449 0.5215686
22  5000    80 1.0965831 0.04000842 1.0181662 1.1749999
23  9600    80 1.7423820 0.04216278 1.6597426 1.8250214
24 14000    80 2.3601027 0.04684598 2.2682842 2.4519212
25 19000    80 3.0620580 0.05442428 2.9553860 3.1687300
```

What causes this error?

Comment: The problem is that you are coloring by `cut`, but random effects are not given in `Effect`. (i.e. there is no `cut` in `as.data.frame(ee)`)

Comment: `ggplot(as.data.frame(ee), aes(price, fit)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~depth)` reproduces the `lattice` plot you show.